# Rails 4.1 link_to delete gives incorrect path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason I am unable to get the correct path for my destroy operation of a very simple model.  Are my expectations incorrect?

My routes.rb includes:

```
resources :designs
```

And my view contains:

```
<% @designs.each do |design| %>
<%= link_to "Delete", design, :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Which results in the HTML:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/designs.49" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

Which of course errors on

```
"No route for [DELETE] for /designs.49"
```

When I was expecting the rendered HTML to be:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/designs/49" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

Especially considering rake routes shows me:

```
 DELETE /designs/:id(.:format)                      designs#destroy
```

My workaround is to replace: link_to "Delete", design... with: link_to "Delete", "/designs/#{design.id}"...  (which works fine), but surely I am overlooking something basic, as no one should have to waste this much time to figure out the absolute most fundamental baseline case for a destroy operation.

Comment: I think it is due to deprecation of `link_to` function from `rails 4.1`

Comment: @G.B `link_to_function` is deprecated, but from what I understand, `link_to` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the view could read like this using a `_path` helper:

```
<% @designs.each do |design| %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", design_path(design), :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

But I guess I can see what you're trying to accomplish. To get the `show` action, you should be able to do this:

```
<% @designs.each do |design| %>
  <%= link_to "Show", design %>
<% end %>
```

I wonder if this is a bug in Rails? What happens if you do this?

```
<% @designs.each do |design| %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", url_for(design), :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: All three of these yield the same result.  However, I found the issue and as expected, it is operator error.  There was a prior rule for:   get "design" => ... , an artifact of creating the project initially.  What a schmoe I am.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replacing this in the helper tag.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", design_path, :method => :delete %>
```